# Using ifelse with transform in ddply

Tags: r, plyr, lubridate

I am trying to use `ddply` with `transform` to populate a new variable (`summary_Date`) in a dataframe with variables `ID` and `Date`.  The value of the variable is chosen based on the length of the piece that is being evaluated using `ifelse`:

If there are less than five observations for an ID in a given month, I want to have `summary_Date` be calculated by rounding the date to the nearest month (using `round_date` from package `lubridate`); if there are more than five observations for an ID in a given month, I want the `summary_Date` to simply be `Date`.

```
require(plyr)
require(lubridate)

test.df <- structure(
  list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
                , 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
       , Date = structure(c(-247320000, -246196800, -245073600, -243864000
                            , -242654400, -241444800, -126273600, -123595200
                            , -121176000, -118497600, 1359385200, 1359388800
                            , 1359392400, 1359396000, 1359399600, 1359403200
                            , 1359406800, 1359410400, 1359414000, 1359417600
                            , 55598400, 56116800, 58881600, 62078400, 64756800
                            , 67348800, 69854400, 72964800, 76161600, 79012800
                            , 1358589600, 1358676000, 1358762400, 1358848800
                            , 1358935200, 1359021600, 1359108000, 1359194400
                            , 1359280800, 1359367200), tzone = "GMT"
                          , class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
       , Val=rnorm(40))
  , .Names = c("ID", "Date", "Val"), row.names = c(NA, 40L)
  , class = "data.frame")

test.df <- ddply(test.df, .(ID, floor_date(Date, "month")), transform
                 , summary_Date=as.POSIXct(ifelse(length(ID)<5
                                                  , round_date(Date, "month")
                                                  ,Date)
                                           , origin="1970-01-01 00:00.00"
                                           , tz="GMT")
                 # Included length_x to easily see the length of the subset
                 , length_x = length(ID))

head(test.df,5)
#   floor_date(Date, "month") ID                Date        Val summary_Date length_x
# 1                1962-03-01  1 1962-03-01 12:00:00 -0.1037988   1962-03-01        3
# 2                1962-03-01  1 1962-03-14 12:00:00  0.2923056   1962-03-01        3
# 3                1962-03-01  1 1962-03-27 12:00:00  0.4435410   1962-03-01        3
# 4                1962-04-01  1 1962-04-10 12:00:00  0.1159164   1962-04-01        2
# 5                1962-04-01  1 1962-04-24 12:00:00  2.9824075   1962-04-01        2
```

The `ifelse` statement seems to be working, but the value in 'summary_Date' seems to be the first value calculated for the subset that transform is working on, rather than the row-specific value.  For example in row 3, `summary_Date` should be `1962-04-01` because the date `1962-03-27 12:00:00'` should be rounded up (because there are fewer than five rows in the subset), but instead the first calculated value of `summary_Date` (`1962-03-01`) is repeated in all rows in that subset.

**EDIT:** I was inspired by Ricardo's answer using `data.table` to try it in two steps with `ddply`.  It works also:

```
test.df <- ddply(test.df, .(ID, floor_date(Date, "month")), transform
                 , length_x = length(ID))

test.df <- ddply(test.df, .(ID, floor_date(Date, "month")), transform
                 , summary_Date=as.POSIXct(ifelse(length_x<5
                                                  , round_date(Date, "month")
                                                  ,Date)
                                           , origin="1970-01-01 00:00.00"
                                           , tz="GMT"))

head(test.df,5)[c(1,3:7)]
#   floor_date(Date, "month") ID                Date        Val length_x summary_Date
# 1                1962-03-01  1 1962-03-01 12:00:00 -0.1711212        3   1962-03-01
# 2                1962-03-01  1 1962-03-14 12:00:00 -0.1531571        3   1962-03-01
# 3                1962-03-01  1 1962-03-27 12:00:00  0.1256238        3   1962-04-01
# 4                1962-04-01  1 1962-04-10 12:00:00  1.4481225        2   1962-04-01
# 5                1962-04-01  1 1962-04-24 12:00:00 -0.6508731        2   1962-05-01
```

Comment: Hi @AndyT, I'm a bit confused:  You are saying that row 4, `summary_Date` should be `1962-04-01` -- which is the value that you have in your output.  I'm not seeing what the error is?

Comment: Whoops - that's my mistake.  I mean row 3.  `1962-03-27` should be rounded up to `1962-04-01` because there are fewer than 5 rows in the subset. I've edited it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are counting?  Is it the number of ID's per a given month?

Comment: It is the number of IDs in a given month for a given ID; i.e., the length of the vector ID in the subset for a given ID and month (I could have chosen any of the data frame columns).  Normally I would use `nrow(x)` where `x` is the subset that transform is working on in each iteration of ddply, but I don't have a dataframe name to pass to `nrow`.

Comment: Use `mutate` instead of transform, and you can combine the two `ddply` calls into one. The difference is that `mutate` respects newly created columns, while `transform` does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One Step `ddply` solution (also posted as comment)

```
ddply(test.df, .(ID, floor_date(Date, "month")), mutate, 
  length_x = length(ID), 
  summary_Date=as.POSIXct(ifelse(length_x < 5, round_date(Date, "month") ,Date)
    , origin="1970-01-01 00:00.00", tz="GMT")
)
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Ramnath.  I tried this using transform and obviously got the error of `length_x not found`.  I didn't know about mutate, so thanks for that!

Comment: I also see in the help for `mutate` that it is faster than `transform` - nice for me here because the data frame I'm dealing with is rather large and this operation is quite slow with `transform`.

Comment: For large data frames, I would go with `data.table` since it is usually orders faster than `plyr`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# transform to data.table
library(data.table)
test.dt <- data.table(test.df)

# calculate length of id by month-year. 
test.dt[, idlen := length(ID),  by=list(month(Date), year(Date)) ]

# calculate the summary date
test.dt[, summary_Date := ifelse(idlen<5, as.Date(round_date(Date, "month")), as.Date(Date))]

# If you would like to have it formatted add the following: 
test.dt[, summary_Date := as.Date(summary_Date, origin="1970-01-01")]
```

#### Results:

```
 > test.dt
    ID                Date         Val idlen summary_Date
 1:  1 1962-03-01 12:00:00  0.42646422     3   1962-03-01
 2:  1 1962-03-14 12:00:00 -0.29507148     3   1962-03-01
 3:  1 1962-03-27 12:00:00  0.89512566     3   1962-04-01   <~~~~~
 4:  1 1962-04-10 12:00:00  0.87813349     2   1962-04-01
 5:  1 1962-04-24 12:00:00  0.82158108     2   1962-05-01
 6:  1 1962-05-08 12:00:00  0.68864025     1   1962-05-01
```

---

### UPDATE:

#### Explanation of why two steps are needed

The reason it cannot be done in one step has to do with the fact that you are only getting a single value per group. When you assign that value to the members of the group, you are assigning 1 element to many. `R` knows how to handle such situations very well: `recycling` the single element.

However, in this specifica case, you do not want to recycle;  Rather, you do not want to apply the `1` element to `many`. Therefore, you need unique groups, which is what we do in the second step. Each element (row) of the group then gets assigned its own, specific value.

#### UPDATE 2:

@Ramnath gave a great suggestion of using `mutate`.  Taking a look at `?mutate`, it gives:

> This function is very similar to transform but it executes the transformations iteratively ... 
>   later transformations can use the columns created by earlier transformations

Which is exactly what you want to do!

Comment: This did do it - thanks Ricardo.  Your answer led me to trying it with `ddply` in two steps like you did with `data.table`.  It works that way as well - see my edit in my original post.  I'm still not sure why it can't be done in one step, but I will go with this for now.