# ifelse statement in time

Tags: r, if-statement

My issue is I'm trying to see if `TimeA` comes before `TimeB` so I am doing

```
ifelse(timeA < timeb, 0, 1)
```

I get:

```
1: In Ops.factor(TimeA, TimeB) : < not meaningful for factors.
```

So how do I convert my time format so that it isn't a factor? My current time format is hh:mm:ss?

Comment: In what context? You absolutely can, but in so many ways that you're unlikely to get a useful answer without making your question more specific. I suspect `ifelse` may help, though.

Comment: Please go through the earlier post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164759/using-ifelse-with-transform-in-ddply)

Comment: Your time variable is in hour minutes (from your earlier post), so you need to format that before using `ifelse`. You can provide the sample example along with the code, but please don't repeat the same question again and again.

Comment: Please post the result of `dput(head(timeA))` and `dput(head(timeB))`.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer sounds like it is right there in the error message:

```
1: In Ops.factor(TimeA, TimeB) : < not meaningful for factors.
```

`factor`s don't have an explicit numeric value for comparison's sake. Consider:

```
factor("chicken") < factor("beef")
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#In Ops.factor(factor("chicken"), factor("beef")) :
#  < not meaningful for factors
```

You're comparing things which aren't mathematically comparable (though chicken is clearly the tastier meat if you ask me). If you are comparing unformatted time values as @Metrics suggests, you are essentially repeating the same problem as above.

```
factor("09:05:10") < factor("09:05:20")
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#In Ops.factor(factor("09:05:10"), factor("09:05:20")) :
#  < not meaningful for factors
```

But if you specify the values formally as date/time values, which are essentially numeric values, then you are sweet:

```
as.POSIXct("09:05:10",format="%H:%M:%S") < as.POSIXct("09:05:20","%H:%M:%S")
```

Just remember, unless you can represent your data sensible/meaningfully in a numeric form, then you can't sensible/meaningfully check if one value is larger or smaller than another.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for time values? My current time format is hh:mm:ss?

Comment: @JuniorR - i've edited, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12034526/496803

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked. Cant up vote you :(

Comment: @Junior : You can still accept the answer if you think this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Chicken tastier than beef?!?  WTF are you on?

Comment: @Dason - perhaps a debate for http://cooking.stackexchange.com/ ?